# How to calculate the sum of 2 inputs using a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have asked the user to input the 2 numbers (x & y) and I need to calculate the sum of numbers from x to y and store the final value in the variable using for loop.

The output that I have was

Please enter the value of x: 3

Please enter the value of y: 4

It ended with no summation and no error message.

```
x = input("Please enter the value of x: ")
y = input("Please enter the value of y: ")
if x.isnumeric() and y.isnumeric():
    num1 = int(x)
    num2 = int(y)
else:
    print("One or more of your inputs are not numeric!")
for sum_of_numbers in (num1, num2):
    totalsum=num1
    if totalsum <= num2:
        totalsum=num1+1
    else:
        print("The sum of numbers between " + str(num1) + " and " + str(num2) + " is " + str(totalsum))
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to use the closed form expression for the sum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation). To calculate the sum of all numbers between x and y, you could use this expression to calculate (the sum of numbers 1 ... y) - (the sum of numbers 1 ... x)

Comment: As was pointed out in your similar question yesterday, you can **not** rely on being able to convert a string to int if *isnumeric()* is True

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `range` to iterate over the numbers from `num1` to `num2`.
For each iteration of the for loop, you add the current `num` coming from the range to the `totalsum`
Note that we have done `num2 + 1` instead of `num2`, since range is not inclusive of the second parameter.

```py
x = input("Please enter the value of x: ")
y = input("Please enter the value of y: ")

if x.isnumeric() and y.isnumeric():
    num1 = int(x)
    num2 = int(y)

    totalsum = 0
    for num in range(num1, num2 + 1):
        totalsum += num

    print(
        "The sum of numbers between "
        + str(num1)
        + " and "
        + str(num2)
        + " is "
        + str(totalsum)
    )

else:
    print("One or more of your inputs are not numeric!")
```

A better way to solve this problem is to directly use `sum` in python, as shown below.

`totalsum = sum(range(num1, num2 + 1))`

An even better way is to directly use the [mathematical formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation). The sum of numbers between x and y is the sum of numbers till y subtracted by the sum of numbers till x (but not including x). The following code shows the same.

`totalsum = num2 * (num2 + 1) // 2 - (num1 - 1) * num1 // 2`

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop to calculate the total isn't optimum but that's the requirement so:

```
x = input("Input value for X: ")
y = input("Input value for Y: ")

try:
    total = 0
    for n in range(int(x), int(y)): # add 1 to the 2nd argument if range is to be inclusive
        total += n
    print(f"The sum of numbers between {x} and {y} is {total}")
except ValueError:
    print("One or more of your inputs are not numeric!")
```